# Multiply strings in C

Tags: c, string

I wrote a simple program to multiply a string a defined times.
But, it doesn't really work, and don't know why...

It's so simple that I don't know what the problem could be...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *product(char *str, int k);

int main()
{
    char strg[1000];
    char *prod;
    int mult;

    scanf("%s", strg);
    scanf("%d", mult);

    prod = product(strg, mult);

    printf("%s\n", prod);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *product(char *str, int k)
{
    int i, j;
    int len = strlen(str);
    char *res = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (len * k + 1));

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < (len * k); i++, j++)
    {
            if (j == len) j = 0;

            res[i] = str[j];
    }

    res[++i] = '\0';

    return res;
}
```

Anyone who can help me to figure out where's the problem? :D

Comment: You need space for the terminator.

Comment: `scanf("%d", mult);` ---> `scanf("%d", &mult);`

Comment: Recheck the code now...

Comment: Lol forget the dereferencing for "mult", n00bs mistakes, now it works, thanks! :)

Comment: You really should get into the habit of `free`ing memory you no longer need.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1 - always.  If you feel the need to check the size of of a string element, `sizeof(*str)` would make more sense, in case the data type 0f `str` were ever changed (to `wchar_t` for example)

Comment: @pmg It's not so important here, just a simple program to test the function. Moreover, at the exit of the program all the memory allocated runtime is free'd, so for now I do not care of that.

Answer (score 3):

At the end of the loop, `i` is already the index of the position for the terminator.

Just do

```
res[i] = 0;
```

Comment: Also, your malloc should be of size (sizeof(char) * ((len * k) + 1)), although sizeof(char) is 1 so you could just remove it.